# keycloak cannot connect to postgres when containerized

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

I have the following docker-compose

```
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    ports:
      - 9800:8080
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: postgres_db
      DB_PORT: 5433
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
```

When run, I am able to connect with a database client to the postgres_db container with the provided credentials but Keycloak container doesn't want to start because it cannot reach postgres.

```
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to postgres_db:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
        ... 62 more
```

Keycloak has also a sample docker-compose file for configuring it with Postgres: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-postgres.yml

I also tried replacing `DB_ADDR: postgres_db` with `DB_ADDR: localhost` or `DB_ADDR: postgres_db:5433` or `DB_ADDR: localhost:5433` and it didn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried launching the db container first, waiting about a minute or five and then launching keycloack ? It might be an initialization problem on the db hand : the container is launched but the dbms is not yet fully initialized and accepting connections

Comment: I did, I waited until I was able to connect to postgres

Comment: You always need to use the standard port number (for PostgreSQL, 5432) when connecting between containers, so set `DB_PORT: '5432'`.  The `ports:` aren't used here (and aren't required if you don't need access to the database from outside Docker).